# php call a class method from a callback parameter

Tags: php, class, parameters, callback

From Class A I want to implement a callback that includes specific methods as parameters. Eg.

```
    call_user_func_array($callback, ['$this->get', '$this->post']);
```

However this doesn't work. What I am aiming for here is to do this:

index.php

```
    $API = new API();
    $API->state('/users', function ($get, $post) {
        $get('/', 'UserController.getAll');
    });
```

API.php

```
    public function state ($state, $callback) {
        call_user_func_array($callback, ['$this->get', '$this->post']);
    }

    public method get ($uri, $ctrl)  { echo 'getting'; }
    public method post ($uri, $ctrl) { echo 'posting'; }
```

Thanks for any input!
I do realize using $this->method, won't work as $this-> will not exist within the callback scope.

Comment: My PHP version is 5.5.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that i somehow had to bind $this to the correct scope.
I managed to do that by including $this (the class instant) with each parameter:

```
call_user_func_array($callback, [ [$this, 'get'] ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

because you are using object methods and not global functions as callback, you must use `call_user_method_array` instead of `call_user_func_array`.

Comment: This will give me the comment: only variables can be passed back as parameters. After reading about it i can see this is deprecated, and completely removed in php 7

Comment: [`call_user_method_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-method-array.php) is deprecated since PHP 4.1.0 and was removed with PHP 7.

Comment: As i see in the php documentation, `call_user_method_array` is deprecated; you should use `call_user_func_array(array($this, $callback), $params);` now.

Comment: You should read the docs again, the first parameter should be a callable variable. not an array.

Comment: Now I feel pretty stupid, what I should have said was: "i get the error: () expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, second array member is not a valid method"

Answer (score 0):

If you need access to only public members and methods then one possible solution can be this:

```
class API{
  public function state ($state, $callback) {
      call_user_func($callback, $this);
  }

  public function get ($uri, $ctrl)  { echo 'getting'; }
  public function post ($uri, $ctrl) { echo 'posting'; }
}

$API = new API();
$API->state('/users', function ($context) {
    $context->get('/', 'UserController.getAll');
});
```

Comment: If i wanted to do that, it would be easier to just add the $API into the function scope rather than including the this variable from within the class scope itself.